# How to get nuget.exe visible for powershell?

Tags: .net, powershell, deployment, build, nuget

I'm trying to get nuget running on my buildserver. As you can see in the screenshot, it has been added to $env:path but can't be invoked. Does somebody encountered similar problems and has a solution for me?

Kind regards
Paul

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Path variable points to the .exe not the directory. It has to be "C:\program files\nuget" instead.